# Efficient slicing of symmetric sparse matrices

Tags: python, cython, slice, sparse-matrix

I have a list of sparse symmetric matrices `sigma` such that

```
len(sigma) = N
```

and for all `i,j,k`,

```
sigma[i].shape[0] == sigma[i].shape[1] = m  # Square
sigma[i][j,k] == sigma[i][k,j]  # Symmetric
```

I have an indexing array `P` such that

```
P.shape[0] = N
P.shape[1] = k
```

My objective is to extract the `k x k` dense submatrices of `sigma[i]` using the indexing given by `P[i,:]`. This can be done as follows

```
sub_matrices = np.empty([N,k,k])
for i in range(N):
    sub_matrices[i,:,:] = sigma[i][np.ix_(P[i,:], P[i,:])].todense()
```

Note however that while `k` is small, `N` (and `m`) are very large. If the sparse symmetric matrices are stored in CSR format this takes a very long time. I feel there must be a better solution. For example is there a sparse format that lends itself well to symmetric matrices that need to be sliced on both dimensions?

I am using Python but would be open to any C library suggestions that I could interface using Cython.

**EXTRA**

Note that my current Cython approach is as follows:

```
cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

@cython.boundscheck(False) # turn off bounds-checking for entire function
cpdef sparse_slice_fast_cy(sigma,
                           long[:,:] P,
                           double[:,:,:] sub_matrices):
    """
    Inputs:
        sigma: A list (N,) of sparse sp.csr_matrix (m x m)
        P: A 2D array of integers (N, k)
        sub_matrices: A 3D array of doubles (N, k, k) containing the slicing
    """
    # Create variables for keeping code tidy
    cdef long N = P.shape[0]
    cdef long k = P.shape[1]

    cdef long i
    cdef long j
    cdef long index_pointer 
    cdef long sparse_row_pointer

    # Create objects for holding sparse matrix data
    cdef double[:] data
    cdef long[:] indices
    cdef long[:] indptr

    # Object for the ordered P
    cdef long[:] perm

    # Make sure sub_matrices is all 0
    sub_matrices[:] = 0

    for i in range(N):
        # Sort the P
        perm = np.argsort(P[i,:])

        # Get the sparse matrix values
        data     = sigma[i].data
        indices  = sigma[i].indices.astype(long)
        indptr   = sigma[i].indptr.astype(long)

        for j in range(k):
            # Loop over row P[i, perm[j]] in sigma searching for values
            # in P[i, :] vector i.e. compare
            #     sigma[P[i, perm[j], :]
            # against
            #     P[i,:]

            # To do this we need our sparse row vector with columns 
            #     indices[indptr[P[i, perm[j]]], indptr[P[i, perm[j]]+1]]
            # and data/values
            #     data[indptr[P[i, perm[j]]], indptr[P[i, perm[j]]+1]]
            # which comes from the csr matrix format.
            # We also need our sorted indexing vector
            #     P[i, perm[:]]

            # We begin by pointing at the top of both
            # our vectors and gradually move down them. In the event of 
            # an equality we add the data to sub_matrices[i,:,:] and 
            # increment the INDEXING VECTOR pointer, not the sparse
            # row vector pointer, as there can be multiple values that 
            # are the same in the indexing vector but not the sparse row
            # column vector (only 1 column can appear in 1 row!).
            index_pointer = 0
            sparse_row_pointer = indptr[P[i, perm[j]]]

            while ((index_pointer < k) and (sparse_row_pointer < indptr[P[i, perm[j]] + 1])):
                if indices[sparse_row_pointer] == P[i, perm[index_pointer]]:
                    # We can add data to sub_matrices
                    sub_matrices[i, perm[j], perm[index_pointer]] = \
                           data[sparse_row_pointer]

                    # Only increment the index pointer
                    index_pointer += 1
                elif indices[sparse_row_pointer] > P[i, perm[index_pointer]]:
                    # Need to increment index pointer
                    index_pointer += 1
                else:
                    # Need to increment sparse row pointer
                    sparse_row_pointer += 1
```

I believe then `np.argsort` may be inefficient when called often on relatively small vectors and would like to swap for a C implementation. I also don't take advantage of parallel processing that could potentially speed it up over the `N` sparse matrices. Unfortunately as there are Python coercions inside the outer, loop I don't know how I can use `prange`.

Another point to note is that the Cython approach seems to use a HUGE amount of memory but I have no idea where its getting allocated.

**Latest Version**

As per the suggestions of ead, below is the latest version of the Cython code

```
cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

@cython.boundscheck(False) # turn off bounds-checking for entire function
cpdef sparse_slice_fast_cy(sigma,
                           np.ndarray[np.int32_t, ndim=2] P,
                           np.float64_t[:,:,:] sub_matrices,
                           int symmetric):
    """
    Inputs:
        sigma: A list (N,) of sparse sp.csr_matrix (m x m)
        P: A 2D array of integers (N, k)
        sub_matrices: A 3D array of doubles (N, k, k) containing the slicing
        symmetric: 1 if the sigma matrices are symmetric
    """
    # Create variables for keeping code tidy
    cdef np.int32_t N = P.shape[0]
    cdef np.int32_t k = P.shape[1]

    cdef np.int32_t i
    cdef np.int32_t j
    cdef np.int32_t index_pointer 
    cdef np.int32_t sparse_row_pointer

    # Create objects for holding sparse matrix data
    cdef np.float64_t[:] data
    cdef np.int32_t[:] indices

    cdef np.int32_t[:] indptr

    # Object for the ordered P
    cdef np.int32_t[:,:] perm = np.argsort(P, axis=1).astype(np.int32)

    # Make sure sub_matrices is all 0
    sub_matrices[:] = 0

    for i in range(N):
        # Get the sparse matrix values
        data     = sigma[i].data
        indices  = sigma[i].indices
        indptr   = sigma[i].indptr

        for j in range(k):
            # Loop over row P[i, perm[j]] in sigma searching for values
            # in P[i, :] vector i.e. compare
            #     sigma[P[i, perm[j], :]
            # against
            #     P[i,:]

            # To do this we need our sparse row vector with columns 
            #     indices[indptr[P[i, perm[j]]], indptr[P[i, perm[j]]+1]]
            # and data/values
            #     data[indptr[P[i, perm[j]]], indptr[P[i, perm[j]]+1]]
            # which comes from the csr matrix format.
            # We also need our sorted indexing vector
            #     P[i, perm[:]]

            # We begin by pointing at the top of both
            # our vectors and gradually move down them. In the event of 
            # an equality we add the data to sub_matrices[i,:,:] and 
            # increment the INDEXING VECTOR pointer, not the sparse
            # row vector pointer, as there can be multiple values that 
            # are the same in the indexing vector but not the sparse row
            # column vector (only 1 column can appear in 1 row!).

            if symmetric:
                index_pointer = j  # Only search upper triangular
            else:
                index_pointer = 0
            sparse_row_pointer = indptr[P[i, perm[i, j]]]

            while ((index_pointer < k) and (sparse_row_pointer < indptr[P[i, perm[i, j]] + 1])):
                if indices[sparse_row_pointer] == P[i, perm[i, index_pointer]]:
                    # We can add data to sub_matrices
                    sub_matrices[i, perm[i, j], perm[i, index_pointer]] = \
                           data[sparse_row_pointer]

                    if symmetric:
                        sub_matrices[i, perm[i, index_pointer], perm[i, j]] = \
                               data[sparse_row_pointer]

                    # Only increment the index pointer
                    index_pointer += 1
                elif indices[sparse_row_pointer] > P[i, perm[i, index_pointer]]:
                    # Need to increment index pointer
                    index_pointer += 1
                else:
                    # Need to increment sparse row pointer
                    sparse_row_pointer += 1
```

**Parallel Version**

Below is a parallel version, although it doesn't seem to provide any speedup and the code is no longer as nice looking:

```
# See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48805636/efficient-slicing-of-symmetric-sparse-matrices
cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
from cython.parallel import prange

@cython.boundscheck(False) # turn off bounds-checking for entire function
cpdef sparse_slice_fast_cy(sigma,
                           np.ndarray[np.int32_t, ndim=2] P,
                           np.float64_t[:,:,:] sub_matrices,
                           int symmetric):
    """
    Inputs:
        sigma: A list (N,) of sparse sp.csr_matrix (m x m)
        P: A 2D array of integers (N, k)
        sub_matrices: A 3D array of doubles (N, k, k) containing the slicing
        symmetric: 1 if the sigma matrices are symmetric
    """
    # Create variables for keeping code tidy
    cdef np.int32_t N = P.shape[0]
    cdef np.int32_t k = P.shape[1]

    cdef np.int32_t i
    cdef np.int32_t j
    cdef np.int32_t index_pointer 
    cdef np.int32_t sparse_row_pointer

    # Create objects for holding sparse matrix data
    cdef np.float64_t[:] data_mem_view
    cdef np.int32_t[:] indices_mem_view
    cdef np.int32_t[:] indptr_mem_view

    cdef np.float64_t **data = <np.float64_t **> malloc(N * sizeof(np.float64_t *))
    cdef np.int32_t **indices = <np.int32_t **> malloc(N * sizeof(np.int32_t *))
    cdef np.int32_t **indptr = <np.int32_t **> malloc(N * sizeof(np.int32_t *))

    for i in range(N):
        data_mem_view = sigma[i].data
        data[i] = &(data_mem_view[0])

        indices_mem_view = sigma[i].indices
        indices[i] = &(indices_mem_view[0])

        indptr_mem_view = sigma[i].indptr
        indptr[i] = &(indptr_mem_view[0])

    # Object for the ordered P
    cdef np.int32_t[:,:] perm = np.argsort(P, axis=1).astype(np.int32)

    # Make sure sub_matrices is all 0
    sub_matrices[:] = 0

    for i in prange(N, nogil=True):
        for j in range(k):
            # Loop over row P[i, perm[j]] in sigma searching for values
            # in P[i, :] vector i.e. compare
            #     sigma[P[i, perm[j], :]
            # against
            #     P[i,:]
            # To do this we need our sparse row vector with columns 
            #     indices[indptr[P[i, perm[j]]], indptr[P[i, perm[j]]+1]]
            # and data/values
            #     data[indptr[P[i, perm[j]]], indptr[P[i, perm[j]]+1]]
            # which comes from the csr matrix format.
            # We also need our sorted indexing vector
            #     P[i, perm[:]]

            # We begin by pointing at the top of both
            # our vectors and gradually move down them. In the event of 
            # an equality we add the data to sub_matrices[i,:,:] and 
            # increment the INDEXING VECTOR pointer, not the sparse
            # row vector pointer, as there can be multiple values that 
            # are the same in the indexing vector but not the sparse row
            # column vector (only 1 column can appear in 1 row!).

            if symmetric:
                index_pointer = j  # Only search upper triangular
            else:
                index_pointer = 0
            sparse_row_pointer = indptr[i][P[i, perm[i, j]]]

            while ((index_pointer < k) and 
                   (sparse_row_pointer < indptr[i][P[i, perm[i, j]] + 1])):
                if indices[i][sparse_row_pointer] == P[i, perm[i, index_pointer]]:
                    # We can add data to sub_matrices
                    sub_matrices[i, perm[i, j], perm[i, index_pointer]] = \
                           data[i][sparse_row_pointer]

                    if symmetric:
                        sub_matrices[i, perm[i, index_pointer], perm[i, j]] = \
                               data[i][sparse_row_pointer]

                    # Only increment the index pointer
                    index_pointer = index_pointer + 1
                elif indices[i][sparse_row_pointer] > P[i, perm[i, index_pointer]]:
                    # Need to increment index pointer
                    index_pointer = index_pointer + 1
                else:
                    # Need to increment sparse row pointer
                    sparse_row_pointer = sparse_row_pointer + 1

    # Free malloc'd data
    free(data)
    free(indices)
    free(indptr)
```

**Test**

To test the code run

```
cythonize -i sparse_slice.pyx
```

where `sparse_slice.pyx` is th filename. Then you can use this script:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.sparse
from sparse_slice import sparse_slice_fast_cy

k = 100
N = 20000
m = 10000
samples = 20

# Create sigma matrices
## The sampling of random sparse takes a while so just do a few and 
## then populate with these.
now = time.time()
sigma_samples = []
for i in range(samples):
    sigma_samples.append(sp.sparse.rand(m, m, density=0.001, format='csr'))
    sigma_samples[-1] = sigma_samples[-1] + sigma_samples[-1].T  # Symmetric

## Now make the sigma list from these.
sigma = []
for i in range(N):
    j = np.random.randint(samples)
    sigma.append(sigma_samples[j])
print('Time to make sigma: {}'.format(time.time() - now))

# Create indexer
now = time.time()
P = np.empty([N, k]).astype(int)
for i in range(N):
    P[i, :] = np.random.choice(np.arange(m), k, replace=True)
print('Time to make P: {}'.format(time.time() - now))

# Create objects for holding the slices
sub_matrices_slow = np.empty([N, k, k])
sub_matrices_fast = np.empty([N, k, k])

# Run both slicings
## Slow
now = time.time()
for i in range(N):
    sub_matrices_slow[i,:,:] = sigma[i][np.ix_(P[i,:], P[i,:])].todense()
print('Time to make sub_matrices_slow: {}'.format(time.time() - now))

## Fast
symmetric = 1
now = time.time()
sparse_slice_fast_cy(sigma, P.astype(np.int32), sub_matrices_fast, symmetric)
print('Time to make sub_matrices_fast: {}'.format(time.time() - now))

assert(np.all((sub_matrices_slow - sub_matrices_fast)**2 < 1e-6))
```

Comment: What are your timings (for given N,k) and which speed-up would you like to  achieve? I think CSR isn't a bad choice for this kind of problems.

Comment: (N,k) are approximately (300,000, 100). Its taking around 2 minutes to perform.

Comment: Scipy sparse does not do any thing special with symmetric matrices.  `csr` matrix index is actually performed with matrix multiplication.  Do you know anything about how these matrices are stored?  It probably is faster to convert `sigma[i]` to dense, and then do the indexing.

Comment: Yep, I know how its stored and tried to write my own slicer in Cython but didn't see much speed up, although that may be my own fault. Converting to dense is out the question unfortunately as dimebsions are too large.

Comment: If you would share your Cython-approach, you would surely get hints, on how to improve (if possible of course). It would be a better question than generic “I want a fast solution”.

Comment: Ok, I'll tidy it up first and then share. Unfortunately its quite complicated (for me at least), although fortunately not too long.

Comment: Please add all imports/cimports you are using, so it is possible to cythonize after copy&paste.

Comment: What do you mean when saying HUGE? Factor 2, 10, 100?

Comment: Its quite hard to measure because I'm just looking at htop (and the fact my system locks up if I use values too large). For the current values in the test script it uses about 3GB more than whats declared in the Python program already. I don't know what's allocating the memory in the Cython code though. Increasing N to around 50000 causes me to run out of memory. Although I just thought it could be `numpy` not allocating the memory for `sub_matrices_fast = np.empty([N, k, k])` and then it happens in one in Cython with `sub_matrices[:] = 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot test right now, but there are two suggestions:

A) sort all rows at once onside of the `i`-loop:

```
# Object for the ordered P
cdef long[:,:] perm = np.argsort(P, axis=1)
```

maybe you will need to pass P as `np.ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim=2] P` (or whatever type it is) to avoid copying. You will have to access the data via `perm[i,X]` instead of `perm[X]`.

B) define

```
cdef np.int32_t[:] indices
cdef np.int32_t[:] indptr
```

So you don't need to copy the data via '.astype`, i.e.

```
for i in range(N):
    data     = sigma[i].data
    indices  = sigma[i].indices
    indptr   = sigma[i].indptr
```

I think because the `sigma[i]` has `O(m)` elements the copying is the bottleneck of your function: you get running time `O(N*(m+k^2))` instead of `O(N*k^2) - it is good to avoid it.

Otherwise the function doesn't look too bad.

For getting `prange` to work with `i`-loop, you should move the accesses to `sigma[i]` outside of the loop by creating a kind of arrays of pointers to the first element of `data` , `indices` and `indptr` and populating them in a cheap preprocess-step. One can make it work, but the question is how much is the gain from the parallelization - it might well be the case, that the problem is memory-bound - one has to see timings.

You could also use the symmetry by processing only the upper triangle matrix:

```
  ...
  index_pointer = j #only upper triangle!
  ....
  ....
     # We can add data to sub_matrices
     #upper triangle sub-matrix:
     sub_matrices[i, perm[j], perm[index_pointer]] = \
                       data[sparse_row_pointer]
     #lower triangle sub-matrix:
     sub_matrices[i, perm[index_pointer], perm[j]] = \
                       data[sparse_row_pointer]
  ....
```

I would start with B) and see how it works out...

---

**Edit:**

On memory usage: one can measure the peak memory usage via

```
 /usr/bin/time -f "peak_used_memory:%M(in Kb)" python test.py
```

I run my tests with `N=2000` and get (python3.6+cython0.27.1):

```
                             peak memory usage
only slow                       245Mb
only fast                       245Mb
slow+fast no check              402Mb
slow+fast+assert                576Mb
```

So there is 50Mb overhead, 200Mb used by either function and additional 176 Mb for evaluation the assert. I can see the same behavior also for other values of `N`.

So I would say there is no huge memory usage by cython.

---

This task is very probably (at least partly) memory bound, so the parallelization will not help much. You should reduce the amount of memory loaded to cache.

One possibility is not to use `perm` - after all it also needs to be loaded into the cache. You could do it if

1. you can live with any  row/col permutation in matrix sigma, than just sort `P` and use it.
2. there are very few elements per row, so linear search for every element would be Ok.
3. doing binary search for every element

I guess you could win about 20-30% in the best case.

Sometimes cython produces code which is not easy to optimize for the c-compiler and one achieves often better results writing directly in C and then wrapping it with python.

But I would do all that only if this operation is really, really the bottle-neck of your program.

---

By the way, declaring

```
cdef np.int64_t[:,:] perm = np.argsort(P, axis=1)
```

you will not need additional copying.

Comment: Great suggestions, the Cython is now much faster. Note that it still uses a huge amount of memory. I don't understand why, as the only object getting created now is `perm`. My only guess is `sigma` may be getting copied.

Comment: @rwolst I was not able to see anything special in memory usage of cython - see my edit for more info.

Comment: I think if I do the maths, then its an expected huge amount of memory. N*k*k*8 (double precision) for the output mafrix looks about right. I think it was a mixture between not ubderstanding the `np.empty` mechanics and I was just getting surprised looking at htop and seeing it all getting allocated at once as opposed to the incremental slow method.